# How to use ltrace for mpi programs?

Tags: mpi, ltrace

I want to know how to use ltrace to get library function calls of mpi application but simply ltrace doesn't work and my mpirun cannot succeed. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to simply use:

```
$ mpiexec -n 4 -other_mpiexec_options ltrace ./executable
```

But that will create a huge mess since the outputs from the different ranks will merge. A much better option is to redirect the output of `ltrace` to a separate file for each rank. Getting the rank is easy with some MPI implementations. For example, Open MPI exports the world rank in the environment variable `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK`. The following wrapper script would help:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ltrace --output trace.$OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK $*
```

Usage:

```
$ mpiexec -n 4 ... ltrace_wrapper ./executable
```

This will produce 4 trace files, one for each rank: `trace.0`, `trace.1`, `trace.2`, and `trace.3`.

For MPICH and other MPI implementations based on it and using the Hydra PM exports `PMI_RANK` and the above given script has to be modified and `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK` replaced with `PMI_RANK`. One could also write an universal wrapper that works with both families of MPI implementations.