# How to observe elapsed time for all processes of an MPI program

Tags: linux, time, parallel-processing, mpi

I want to observe the performance of my MPI program using time command in linux. It shows only real, user and sys values for the program. However, I should examine what happens on each process. So, is there a way to see how long does my program take for each process separately?

Comment: Are you constrained to use the `time` command (or other OS commands)? If you are able to change the code it is a rather simple matter to use `MPI_Wtime`, which would probably be more accurate as well.

Comment: I've used the solution below. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prepend `time` to the `mpiexec`/`mpirun` command, it will show you statistics about the command itself:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -p mpiexec -n 3 sleep 1
real 3.54
user 0.42
sys 0.15
```

To have it report statistics about each MPI rank, you should prepend `time` to the name of the MPI executable:

```
$ mpiexec -n 3 /usr/bin/time -p sleep 1
real 1.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
real 1.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
real 1.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

In order to separate the output from all ranks and determine which is which and from which rank a measurement comes you can use the following with Open MPI:

```
$ mpiexec --tag-output -n 3 /usr/bin/time -p sleep 1
[1,1]<stderr>:real 
[1,1]<stderr>:1.00
[1,1]<stderr>:user 0.00
[1,1]<stderr>:sys 0.00
[1,0]<stderr>:real 1.00
[1,0]<stderr>:user 0.00
[1,0]<stderr>:sys 0.00
[1,2]<stderr>:real 1.00
[1,2]<stderr>:user 0.00
[1,2]<stderr>:sys 0.00
```

Each line is now prefixed by `[1,rank]<stream>:`. You can also write a wrapper named `mpitime.sh` that calls `time` with the option to write the information to a text file, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/time -o timing.$OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK $*
```

Running with `mpiexec -n 3 mpitime.sh sleep 1` will produce three files: `timing.0`, `timing.1`, and `timing.2`, containing the timing for ranks 0, 1, and 2. The wrapper script has to be adapted for other implementations. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681064/1374437).